# How do I get all of the burger bars to change color on hover in my ReactJS/NextJS app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

I have an issue with my hamburger menu where the bars do not all change color when one of the is hovered over. Right now only one of them gets changed when it is hovered over. I am unsure of how I can get them to all change color when any one of them is hovered over.

**How do I get all the hamburger bars to change color when any one of them is hovered?**

Hamburger menu HTML:

```
  <div className="burger-menu" onClick={updateMenu}>
    <div className={burgerClass} ></div>
    <div className={burgerClass} ></div>
    <div className={burgerClass} ></div>
  </div>
```

Hamburger CSS / Bootstrap 5

```
.burger-bar:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .burger-menu {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .burger-bar {
    display: inline;
    width: 3em;
    height: 0.5em;
    background-color: #292f36;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    margin: 2px;
  }

  .nav-item {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width >= 550px) {
  .burger-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .burger-bar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the hamburger icons to turn the color I want by giving each of them a unique id and then changing the colors in a onMouseOver and onMouseLeave event.

```
  const changeBackgroundRed = () => {
      document.getElementById('barOne').style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
      document.getElementById('barTwo').style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
      document.getElementById('barThree').style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
  };

  const changeBackgroundGrey = () => {
    document.getElementById('barOne').style.backgroundColor = '#292f36';
    document.getElementById('barTwo').style.backgroundColor = '#292f36';
    document.getElementById('barThree').style.backgroundColor = '#292f36';
  };


  <div className="burger-menu" onClick={updateMenu}>
    <div id='barOne' className={burgerClass} onMouseOver={changeBackgroundRed} onMouseLeave={changeBackgroundGrey}></div>
    <div id='barTwo' className={burgerClass} onMouseOver={changeBackgroundRed} onMouseLeave={changeBackgroundGrey}></div>
    <div id='barThree' className={burgerClass} onMouseOver={changeBackgroundRed} onMouseLeave={changeBackgroundGrey}></div>
  </div>
```